# add attribute in setup script not work

Tags: attributes, magento-1, setup

i've a setup script in \app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\sql\modulename_setup

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'supplier', array(
  'type'              => 'varchar',
  'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
  'frontend'          => '',
  'label'             => 'Supplier',
  'input'             => 'select',
  'class'             => '',
  'source'            => 'modulename/source_option',
  'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
  'visible'           => true,
  'required'          => true,
  'user_defined'      => true,
  'default'           => '',
  'searchable'        => false,
  'filterable'        => false,
  'comparable'        => false,
  'option'            => array ('value' => 
                               array('optionone' => array('Sony'),
                                     'optiontwo' => array('Samsung'),
                                     'optionthree' => array('Apple'),                                                
                               )
                         ),  
  'visible_on_front'  => false,
  'unique'            => false,
  'group'             => 'Default'
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Module_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <blocks>
           <adminhtml>
               <rewrite>
                   <catalog_product_grid>Module_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
               </rewrite>
           </adminhtml>
       </blocks>
            <resources>
                <modulename_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Module_Modulename</module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_setup>
                <modulename_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_write>
                <modulename_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </modulename_read>
            </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

i want to add a attribute to default group for every product type, but it didn't run, anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: the version number in config.xml is 0.1.0 and install script is mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

Comment: Can you show your config.xml?

Comment: updated ...........

Comment: If you ran the setup once, and a row is in the setup table for your version, the setup script won't run a second time. You need to remove that from the database. Check module entry in "core_resource table" table.

Comment: i know, i use VM to restore everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to add your attribute to one attribute set

```
// make sure they are all in the default set:
$attributeCode        = 'supplier';
$group_name           = 'General';
$entityTypeId         = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$eav_setup            = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$attributeSets = $installer->_conn->fetchAll('select * from '.$this->getTable('eav/attribute_set').' where entity_type_id=?', $entityTypeId);

foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
    //-------------- add attribute to set and group
    $attribute_set_id   = $attributeSet['attribute_set_id'];
    $attribute_group_id = $eav_setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
    $attribute_id       = $eav_setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

     $eav_setup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);

}
```

And in your code, the line

```
 'group'             => 'Default'
```

is not required at all or should look like

```
'group'             => 'General'
```